# tabs not opening on html webpage jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I have made a tabbed menu: http://jsfiddle.net/zWMYp/

However when I add it to my webpage, it does not open the tab content like above: http://jsfiddle.net/vL5VJ/

I am unsure what is interfering with the tabs.

Comment: Can you give us the url of your page..

Comment: Paste the code from your fiddles into your question here.

Comment: the code is too long, hence why i used a JSfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li > div {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

is the culprit. remove it (and add `color: #fff`) and it will work

http://jsfiddle.net/vM5VJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

two issues here in your code
1) the z-index in the div under the a href have z-index of -1 thus it's behind everything else
2) the color of the text is almost the same as background

i've changed this css class as an example, you can use other methods such as define a css color for the div text;

```
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li:target > div
{
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
    color:white;

}
```

here is the updated jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/vM5VJ/3/

my advise is to use google chrome to inspect the element, and incrementally remove or add css to figure out where is the problem.  I never liked looking at the whole code to figure out a very focus issue